# Transfer an object from java to C#

Tags: java, c#, sockets, serialization, serversocket

I have to communicate between Java and C# where i need to send an object through socket server. Here server portion is written in Java and Client portion is written C#. I want to send an object from the server(Java) and receive it in client(C#). But i can't do it.

**LocalJobInfo.java** :

```
package testsocket;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class LocalJobInfo implements Serializable{
    private String id;
    private String message;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

**Server** (in Java) :

```
List<LocalJobInfo> jobInfoList = new ArrayList<LocalJobInfo>();
LocalJobInfo jobInfo = new LocalJobInfo();

jobInfo.setId("1");
jobInfo.setMessage("Success");

jobInfoList.add(jobInfo);

ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4343, 10);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
InputStream is = null;
OutputStream os = null;
String received = null;
try {
       is = socket.getInputStream();
       os = socket.getOutputStream();
       byte[] lenBytes = new byte[4];
       is.read(lenBytes, 0, 4);
       int len = (((lenBytes[3] & 0xff) << 24) | ((lenBytes[2] & 0xff) << 16)
       | ((lenBytes[1] & 0xff) << 8) | (lenBytes[0] & 0xff));
       byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[len];
       is.read(receivedBytes, 0, len);
       received = new String(receivedBytes, 0, len);


       System.out.println("Server received: " + received);

       // Sending

       byte[] toSendBytes = null;
       ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       ObjectOutput out = null;
       try {
               out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
               out.writeObject(jobInfoList);
               out.flush();
               toSendBytes = bos.toByteArray();
       } finally {
                    try {
                        bos.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // ignore close exception
                    }
       }

       int toSendLen = toSendBytes.length;
       byte[] toSendLenBytes = new byte[4];
       toSendLenBytes[0] = (byte) (toSendLen & 0xff);
       toSendLenBytes[1] = (byte) ((toSendLen >> 8) & 0xff);
       toSendLenBytes[2] = (byte) ((toSendLen >> 16) & 0xff);
       toSendLenBytes[3] = (byte) ((toSendLen >> 24) & 0xff);
       os.write(toSendLenBytes);
       os.write(toSendBytes);

       try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
       } catch (Exception ex) {
       }
   } catch (Exception ex) {
   }
   socket.close();
   serverSocket.close();
```

**Client** (in C#) :

```
string toSend = "Hello!";

IPEndPoint serverAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 4343);

Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
clientSocket.Connect(serverAddress);

// Sending
int toSendLen = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(toSend);
byte[] toSendBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toSend);
byte[] toSendLenBytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(toSendLen);
clientSocket.Send(toSendLenBytes);
clientSocket.Send(toSendBytes);

// Receiving
byte[] rcvLenBytes = new byte[4];
clientSocket.Receive(rcvLenBytes);
int rcvLen = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(rcvLenBytes, 0);
byte[] rcvBytes = new byte[rcvLen];
clientSocket.Receive(rcvBytes);

MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
memStream.Write(rcvBytes, 0, rcvBytes.Length);
memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Object obj = (Object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
```

I got an exception during the Deserialize the byte[] in C# client. 
The exception message is : "The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: AC-ED-00-05-73-72-00-17-74-65-73-74-73-6F-63-6B-65 ..."

Now my question is, how can i fix the issue in order to Deserialize in C# code and get the object sent from the server in Java ?

Comment: Use a shared intermediate protocol representation of the object(s) like JSON or XML. You cannot directly serialize an object to binary in Java and expect C# to be able to deserialize it.

Comment: Both Java & C# have different default serialization/deserialization schema, so that you need to standardize the data transfer with third party component (JSON, XML or other text formats). Serializing in one language & deserialize in another often doesn't provide expected results.

Comment: Why don't you send bytes instead of encoding to Ascii?  You aren't decoding the ascii back to bytes.  The send method and receive method must be symmetrical.  Everything you do to send you must do in the reverse order when receiving.

Comment: It works with transforming data in JSON. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a language agnostic serialisation framework. Examples include Google Protocol Buffers, ASN.1, XSD.

Basically you need to turn a schema file (like a GPB .proto, or and ASN.1 .asn, or a .xsd) into both POJO and POCO classes (for Java and C# respectively). That's what the GPB compiler, or an ASN.1 compiler can do for you. Thus you end up with classes in both languages, and these classes serialise / deserialise to / from a common wire format.

XSD is slightly more complex; there's xsd.exe from Microsoft that will turn a .XSD file into C#. I've no idea if there's anything similar for Java.

I think the best place to start is with Google Protocol Buffers - it's free, and will get you going. And it supports both JAVA and C#.

I wouldn't touch JSON schemas; the code generation tools seem to be a long way behind. There's plenty of validators to tell you if a message you have received, or are about to send, conforms to a JSON schema, but that doesn't help you formulate the message in the first place.